# Where i can download ocean sdk

Tags: ocean

I want to see what this ocean really is, but don't have any opprtunity to try/buy it, because i'm just a student. Where i can download ocean sdk, but not from the ocean off.site?
thanx

Answer (score 1):

Their site appears to have a SDK available for students.  When I clicked on the link it took me to [this form](https://www.slb.com/forms/contact/contact_inquiry.aspx?recipientCode=email.product.ocean.getoceannow&service=SO&referringURL=http://www.ocean.slb.com/Pages/contactus.aspx&context=Ocean%20Licensing&serviceSelectable=N&inquiryMode=contactus&SSL=&region=).  Looks like you will need to fill out your info and wait for them to contact you.